# bash file and running the c++ code multiple times

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu to write c++ programs. I am using a bash file to run my program multiple times using different arguments. However, only the first run is executed !

This is my bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop/MyCodeWorkspace

g++ a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp main.cpp -o myProgram

./myProgram 8 0

./myProgram 8 20

./myProgram 8 40

./myProgram 8 60
```

Comment: Does running this in the shell directly produce the desired outcome?

Comment: What is the output generated by your program and script? What does your program do? Does it wait for input at some point? Do you give input when expected?

Comment: Does the first `./myProgram 8 0` actually complete, or does it just hang waiting for input or some such?

Comment: I perfectly agree with what @Cedric said. This script looks like you are trying to automate your build and test procedure.

Comment: Yes the desired outcome is done for ./myProgram 8 0

the program works perfectly if the first and second parameter are hard coded. However, sending them as args works only for the first run  ./myProgram 8 0

Yes I am trying to automate the run, because this is an experiment to test the same algorithm using different arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Probably that your bash program is stuck in the first program.
Make sure that myProgram returns when it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It is my mistake. At the end of my main I have ( int x; cin>>x) so I can pause the terminal(a problem that suddenly happen, and I could not solve). I forgot that I added this line.